# Login to reverse-proxied php app fails over SSL

Tags: php, authentication, reverse-proxy

I've been running a php file-server from behind an apache 2.2 reverse proxy for several years with no issues.

The wan-facing server is SSL'd [https://], the proxied server (on our LAN) that hosts the app isn't.

I'm trying to provision a replacement front-end server, with apache 2.4.

In testing the replacement server, the php auth hangs when proxied from sites-enabled/default-ssl, even though it works fine from sites-enabled/000-default [non-SSL].

Not finding any clues in logs or conf files.

Appreciate any insights or guesses as to where the issue may lie.

Thanks!

Comment: You might need to add the reverse proxy to a whitelist

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is embarrassing ... I omitted two crucial steps, which are both present in the current live front-end server:

a2enmod headers

and

RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" to default-ssl.conf

Bingo.